String type order change and remove a specific character using Pyspark
let's say I have a column like the below



Date




03/2024


07/2024


12/2024


06/2024


01/2024



but I want to change the string order and remove a specific character in the middle



Date




202403


202407


202412


202406


202401



Please help me!

If it is not normal Date then you can deal with it as string
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("03/2024"),
    ("07/2024"),
    ("12/2024"),
    ("06/2024"),
    ("01/2024")],
    StringType())

df = df.withColumn("Split", f.split(df.value,"/"))
df.withColumn("Ordered", f.concat(df.Split[1], df.Split[0])).show()

+-------+----------+-------+
|  value|     Split|Ordered|
+-------+----------+-------+
|03/2024|[03, 2024]| 202403|
|07/2024|[07, 2024]| 202407|
|12/2024|[12, 2024]| 202412|
|06/2024|[06, 2024]| 202406|
|01/2024|[01, 2024]| 202401|
+-------+----------+-------+


Use DATE_FORMAT & TO_DATE functions. Like below.
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(TO_DATE(date, 'MM/yyyy'),'yyyyMM') AS date
FROM 
    VALUES ('03/2024'),('07/2024'),('12/2024'),('06/2024'),('01/2024') 
    AS (date)

+------+
|date  |
+------+
|202403|
|202407|
|202412|
|202406|
|202401|
+------+


But they are string types data though...so I succeeded in removing virgule using F.regexp_replace. now the dataset is 032024, 072024, 122024, 062024, 012024. How can I move the first two letters to the end?

Yes, to_date function will take string and convert it into date format & then use date_format to format date into desired output. You don't need split function here.
